# Error "Encountered the symbol "IN" when expecting one of the following" in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

This is the code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE print_string(IN input_string VARCHAR(255))

BEGIN

DECLARE num_chars INT DEFAULT 0;

IF input_string IS NULL THEN

SET num_chars = 0;

ELSE

SET num_chars = CHAR_LENGTH(input_string);

END IF;

SELECT UPPER(input_string), num_chars;

END;
```

I get error:

```
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "IN" when expecting one of the following:     <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>
current delete exists prior
Errors: check compiler log
```

How do I fix: `current delete exists prior`?

Comment: This is OracleDB rather than MySQL right? (going by the error message)?

Comment: yes, sorry that was mistake

Answer (score 3):

The immediate error is that you have the argument name and mode the wrong way around - it should be `(input_string IN ...` not `(IN input_string ...`. But there are other problems:

- Oracle recommends `VARCHAR2` over `VARCHAR`.
- arguments just have the data type, not a size (or precision/scale), so it should be `(input_string IN VARCHAR2)` not `(input_string IN VARCHAR2(255)`.
- you are missing the IS/AS keyword.
- `DECLARE` comes before `BEGIN` in a PL/SQL block; having a nested block here would be valid, but you're missing a `BEGIN` and `END;` if you do that, and it isn't necessary so I don't think it's what you meant. And you don't need the `DECLARE` at all for a procedure, it's implied.
- if you want a default value for a PL/SQL variable then assign it, rather than using `DEFAULT`. (You don't really need to do this here, as you always assign a value later anyway, but I'm sticking with your general approach.)
- it's probably better to use native Oracle types, so `NUMBER` or `PLS_INTEGER` instead of `INT`.
- assignment of values is with `:=`, not `SET ... = ...`.
- `CHAR_LENGTH` should just be `LENGTH` (unless you have your own function with that name).
- in PL/SQL you have to select *into* something, and *from* something. But if you do that here, you still have to return it to the caller somehow.
- given that you want to 'print' the string, you probably want `dbms_output` - though that relies on the client showing the result, which most don't by default, and it's generally only used for debugging...

So this would work:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE print_string(input_string IN VARCHAR2) AS
  num_chars PLS_INTEGER := 0;
BEGIN
  IF input_string IS NULL THEN
    num_chars := 0;
  ELSE
    num_chars := LENGTH(input_string);
  END IF;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(UPPER(input_string) || ': ' || num_chars);
END;
/
```

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE;
  print_string('This is a test');
END;
/
```

```
1 rows affected

dbms_output:
THIS IS A TEST: 14
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/kVMJ7WQw)

But again, `dbms_output` isn't ideal. And it could be done much more simply (@Mto has shown one way), or without using PL/SQL at all.

Answer (score 2):

You can fix the issues (listing in [@Alex Poole's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74287137/1509264)) and simplify the procedure to:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE print_string(
  input_string IN VARCHAR2
)
IS
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(UPPER(input_string) || ', ' || COALESCE(LENGTH(input_string), 0));
END;
/
```

Then:

```sql
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE;
  print_string('This is a test');
  print_string(NULL);
END;
/
```

Outputs:

> ```
> THIS IS A TEST, 14
> , 0
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/1Uya_TFh)

Answer (score 1):

The code syntax is incorrect here. It should be something like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE print_string(input_string IN VARCHAR2) 
IS
BEGIN
```